# How do I link my image to a HTML file with complicated relative path?

Tags: html, relative-path

This is the directory structure of my `main` folder in `desktop`:

[image]

How do I link the **image.png** inside the **images** folder to the **index.html**, which is located inside the **index** folder, using a relative path?

I tried using: `<image src="../Nexus/Files/Images/image.png">`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe your directory is not accesible by webserver permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
<image src="../Images/image.png">
```

Are the folders "**images**" and "**index**" at the same level?

Answer (score 0):

Try this path i think it will work fine

```
../../Files/Images/image.png
```